# problem during data fetch

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code

`$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ownerId='$UserId'";`
`$result=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die(mysql_error());`
`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)`;

```
<?php
                                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                                        {
                                            echo "<tr>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row['pinId']."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row['usedby']."</td>";
                                            echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
                                            echo "</tr>";
                                        }
                                    ?>
```

**it is ignoring the first record means if 4 rows are in $row its ignoring the 1st one rest three are coming on page.** ownerId is not primary key.

Comment: first do a print_r() of the result and check if all the records are coming.

Comment: @Gaurav priny_r($row) is displaying only thar first row which is not coming in while().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is arising because you already called 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC); once before looping..

try this code...

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE ownerId='$UserId'"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die(mysql_error());

<?php
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>".$row['pinId']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['usedby']."</td>";
   echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 ?>
```

all i have done is removed the 3rd line from your code....